# Overriding onMouseDown in react-grid-layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

How do I override onMouseDown for a GridItem?

I have something like this:

```
class TrackItem extends React.Component {
    onMouseDown(e) {
        this.props.onMouseDown.apply(e);
    }
    render() {
        return <div onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown.bind(this)}>item</div>;
    }
}
```

Which yields the error:

> react-draggable.js:1050 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I don't need `apply`:

```
this.props.onMouseDown(e);
```